# Ошибки при проверки валидатором HTML, возможна проблема с кодировкой PHP

Tags: php, html, валидация

https://validator.w3.org/ выдает следующую ошибку, файл генерируется на PHP, в шаблоне спецсимволов нет.

Error: Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

From line 1, column 1; to line 1, column 6

Дело вообще не в коде а в PHP и кодировке, возможно что-то с mbstring.func_overload
 но было 0 я поставил 2 и ничего перед HTML вставляются какие-то спецсимволы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body class="home header-v3">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: На каком коде возникает ошибка, мы должны сами угадать?

Comment: Дело вообще не в коде а в PHP и кодировке, возможно что-то с mbstring.func_overload
 но было 0 я поставил 2 и ничего перед HTML вставляются какие-то спецсимволы <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body class="home header-v3">

</body>
</html>